# Mock Composer in PHPUnit is actually running

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, composer-php

I'm building a PHP application that needs to access Composer directly. In order to test the application, however, I don't actually want to run composer, so I'm trying to mock it.

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace;

use Composer\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;

class MyTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testComposer()
    {
        /** @var Application|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject $composer */
        $composer = $this->getMockForAbstractClass(Application::class);
        $composer
            ->expects($this->any())
            ->method('run')
            ->will($this->returnValue(true));

        $this->assertTrue(
            $composer->run(new ArrayInput(['command' => 'install']))
        );
    }

}
```

This actually runs the code:

```
$ bin/phpunit -c phpunit-fast.xml tests/MyTest.php
PHPUnit 4.8.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:        PHP 5.6.13-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+3 with Xdebug 2.3.2
Configuration:  phpunit-fast.xml

Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

I've tried various combinations of `->getMock` (which completely fails) and `->getMockBuilder` but it always seems to actually use the `->run` method rather than the stub.

I assume it is somehow replacing these method inside itself, but if that's the case, how to I prevent it?

### Update

It was asked as to why I use `getMockForAbstractClass` rather than just `getMock`.  When using `getMock` I get the following output:

```
PHPUnit 4.8.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:        PHP 5.6.13-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+3 with Xdebug 2.3.2
Configuration:  phpunit.xml.dist

E

Time: 1.19 minutes, Memory: 4.50Mb

There was 1 error:

1) MyNamespace\MyTest::testComposer
PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_RuntimeException: Cannot mock Symfony\Component\Console\Application::setDispatcher() because a class or interface used in the signature is not loaded

tests/MyTest.php:22

Caused by
ReflectionException: Class Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface does not exist

tests/MyTest.php:22

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

This is despite the fact that just using `$composer = new Application();` works fine. In fact, if I add that line above the test, it *still* claims that an `class or interface` wasn't loaded, despite the object being instantiated correctly earlier.

Comment: The composer `Application` class isn't an abstract class. Why are you using `getMockForAbstractClass()` then?

Comment: Good question, I'll update the information above as to why. :)

Comment: It work for me when I do this : $composer = $this->getMock('\Composer\Console\Application');

What do you get when you display Application::class ?

Comment: I do get `Composer\Console\Application` when I echo `Application::class`. Trying `$composer = $this->getMock('\Composer\Console\Application');` as suggested resulted in the same error as above.

Comment: @Bang what version of the package are you using?

Comment: Try to avoid using strings for identifying classes. `::class` is correct and way more elegant. Now the question is: Why are you lacking that interface? Have you looked into the installed dependencies and searched for it? Does it exist? My usual procedure to get mocks is `$this->getMockBuilder(Any::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock()`, because getting a mock shouldn't execute anything. It's tedious, and this is the reason I like using Mockery or Prophecy more.

Comment: Yeah, the problem seems to be that composer requires `"symfony/console": "~2.5"` which require-dev's `"symfony/event-dispatcher": "~2.1"`. Installing all dev dependencies would solve this problem, adding `"symfony/event-dispatcher": "~2.1"` to my dependencies would solve the problem. Yet it also kind of seems like it's not **my** problem to solve. I'm not testing these components there for I should be able to mock them out. :/ I guess I'll open an issue on their github and see what they say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 3 solutions to this:

### 1. Add Event Dispatcher yourself

Add "symfony/event-dispatcher" to your own require-dev

```
"require-dev" : {
    ...
    "symfony/event-dispatcher" : "^2.1"
}
```

With the corrected test:

```
<?php
/**
 * MyTest.php
 */

namespace MyNamespace;

use Composer\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;

class MyTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testComposer()
    {
        /** @var Application|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject $composer */
        $composer = $this->getMock(Application::class);
        $composer
            ->expects($this->any())
            ->method('run')
            ->will($this->returnValue(true));

        $this->assertTrue(
            $composer->run(new ArrayInput(['command' => 'install']))
        );
    }
}
```

***Personal note:*** This feels like a dirty hack but is by far the easiest solution

### 2. Use Prophecy

Use prophecy alongside PHPUnit to mock the console.

```
"require-dev" : {
    ...
    "phpspec/prophecy": "~1.0"
}
```

Now the test looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * MyTest.php
 */

namespace MyNamespace;

use Composer\Console\Application;
use Prophecy\Prophet;
use Prophecy\Prophecy\ObjectProphecy;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;

class MyTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testComposer()
    {
        $prophet = new Prophet();
        $composerProphecy = $prophet->prophesize(Application::class);
        $composerProphecy
            ->run(new ArrayInput(['command' => 'install']))
            ->willReturn(true);

        /** @var Application $composer */
        $composer = $composerProphecy->reveal();

        $this->assertTrue(
            $composer->run(new ArrayInput(['command' => 'install']))
        );
    }
}
```

***Personal note:*** I'm not keen on telling the prophecy what methods will be called using magic methods as these upset my IDE.

### 3. Use Mockery

Another option for the mocking system.

```
"require-dev" : {
    ...
    "mockery/mockery": "^0.9.4"
}
```

And the test:

```
<?php
/**
 * MyTest.php
 */

namespace MyNamespace;

use Composer\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;

class MyTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testComposer()
    {
        /** @var Application|\Mockery\MockInterface $composer */
        $composer = \Mockery::mock(Application::class);
        $composer
            ->shouldReceive('run')
            ->with(ArrayInput::class)
            ->andReturn(true);


        $this->assertTrue(
            $composer->run(new ArrayInput(['command' => 'install']))
        );

        \Mockery::close();
    }
}
```

***Personal note:*** Static usage, having to remember to clean up, and a mis-documented use of a variadic in `shouldReceive` made me very sad.

### 4. (Bonus) Fix Symfony Console

Seems unlikely but if anyone can work out how to fix [#8200](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8200), then that would mean no one would have to use multiple mock frameworks (if you're already using PHPUnit anyway) or add dirty hacks to their require-dev for a single broken test.

Comment: Side note: I went for option 1

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, sorry. :/

TL;DR: getMock variant works for me. Check your environment.

Getting composer via composer (in composer.json require "composer/composer": "@dev") makes the test (using getMock) pass for me.

Check which version of symfony you're using (mine is 2.7.4) and if you're using the phar version of composer (which you probably shouldn't).

Comment: I have tried with dev-master and alpha10, neither work. I'm not using Symfony directly, though some packages are required by some of the tools I am using.

Comment: Well, like Sven said, you should try search your installed dependencies for this interface.
Or you could add symfony as a direct dependency to see if it makes any difference.